# how to send a query from a .sql file?

Tags: mysql, r, odbc, character

#### background:

I am using RMySQL to query a database; I have been doing this successfully with quoted strings, but I would now like to send a longer query from a .sql file.

The sql file is in `mypackage/inst/extdata/myquery.sql`

#### question:

What is the best way to import the query from `myquery.sql` and submit it to a database?

#### What I have tried:

Here is the function that I am working on:

```
library(RMySQL)
library(mypackage)

myqueryfun <- function(...){
   file    <- system.file("extdata", "myquery.sql", package = "mypackage")
   query   <- SOMEFUN(file)
   con     <- dbConnect(...)
   q       <- dbSendQuery(con, query)
   result  <- fetch(q, n = -1)
   return(result)
}
```

So, I am looking for the function `SOMEFUN` and its additional parameters. I have tried `scan` and `readLines`, and I have tried different arguments to these functions, such as `scan(file, sep = '\n', what = 'character')` The closest that I have gotten is `writeLines(readLines(file))`, but I get some error related to parsing the file, like the response to `writeLines(readLines())`:

```
Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function "dbSendQuery", for signature "MySQLConnection", "NULL"
Called from: stop("unable to find an inherited method for function \"", fdef@generic, 
    "\", for signature ", cnames)
```

If the query is a character vector of length 1, such as `"show tables;"`, I get the expected output.

Comment: I think you have answered your own question. The result of your read from file should be a character vector of length 1. So, you could use `paste(..., collapse="")` on the result of your `scan` or `readLines` to collapse the file into a single character string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function that you are looking for, as pointed out by @Andre, wraps `scan` in `paste(scan(...), collapse = "")`:

```
SOMEFUN <- function(file){
    paste(scan(file, sep = "\n", what = "character"), collapse = "")
}
```

Comment: that helps, except that queries separated by a ";" return an error, for example `show tables; show databases` works at the MySQL command line, but not when sent through the R function `dbSendQuery(con, "show tables; show databases;")`

Comment: @Abe you did not specify this in your question. Perhaps if you remove the `paste` wrapper and use `sapply(query, function(x) dbSendQuery(con, x))`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the full answer to your question, but it should help a bit.

You'll notice that it removes the single line comments before the paste() function collapses everything into one line. You don't want a collapsed SQL string like this:

`SELECT * --mycomment FROM etc..`

It won't be treated too kindly by the interpreter, as everything after the first `--` will be ignored.

So try this out...

```
sqlImport <- function(file) {

  sqlStr <- readLines(file)
  sqlStr <- gsub("^[ \t]+","", sqlStr)
  sqlStr <- gsub("^--.*","", sqlStr)
  sqlStr <- paste(sqlStr, collapse=" ")
  return(sqlStr)

}

sqlString <- sqlImport("mysqlfile.sql")
```

Also, this helps make it easy to get the .sql file that you're actually interested in.

```
sqlFiles <- list.files(getwd(), pattern = ".sql$", ignore.case = T)
sqlFiles
sqlString <- sqlImport(sqlFiles[2])  #where you want the second .sql file listed
```